# No. 4: What's the next in this letter sequence?

Tags: pattern, knowledge

Part of a series of similar puzzles - the answer to one will give you the type of thinking required for the others.

What's the next letter in this series? What's the relationship?

```
DN
FRWL
G
T
YOLT
OHMSS
DAF
LALD
```

To be explicit, note the `knowledge` tag below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next letter(s) in the sequence is:

> TMWTGG

The relationship is:

> Acronyms of Bond films, in order of release date.
>  **D**r. **N**o
>  **F**rom **R**ussia **W**ith **L**ove
>  **G**oldfinger
>  **T**hunderball
>  **Y**ou **O**nly **L**ive **T**wice
>  **O**n **H**er **M**ajesty's **S**ecret **S**ervice
>  **D**iamonds **A**re **F**orever
>  **L**ive **A**nd **L**et **D**ie
>
>  and finally:
>  **T**he **M**an **W**ith **T**he **G**olden **G**un

Comment: Good work - really fast!!